# Phpmyadmin Import Data

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I have a Mysql table that looks like this:

```
+-------+
| NAME  |
+-------+
| James |
| Alex  |
| Jones |
| ...   |
+-------+
```

Each name is unique.

And I have a txt file that is a list of names that needs to be imported into this table.

The list needs to be imported keeping the order of the names, but when I use Phpmyadmin to import it, the list seems to get sorted by name prior to being imported.

How can I prevent this behavior? I just need it to be imported as is, without any change. And when I query it should return the results at the same order I inserted them.

Comment: Why do you think PhpMyAdmin imports these records sorting them alphabetically?

Comment: Records in a MySQL table aren't ordered; to retrieve ordered results requires an `ORDER BY` clause.  If you want a non-natural ordering, you will need a separate column (say `order` or `rank`) for this purpose (it can however [automatically increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) so that it yields the order in which records were inserted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default the data being returned from mysql are ordered prior to an indexed column (phpmyadmin has nothing to do with the ordering) if you define an index on the table using the name column the table results will be sorted according to the index of this column but if you want to order them prior to the last insert you have, order them by ID only if you set the ID as an auto_increment column in the design cuase it will automatically increment the values by 1 for the newly inserted rows. :)

Comment: I added a colum named "id" and set it to Auto increment, now it's working :D Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Give each record an ID before importing, then you can sort by ID to get original layout